Elliptic Regularity on Manifolds with Lipschitz Domain and Finite Regularity Boundary
Question:
Let $  \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n $  be a simply connected Lipschitz domain with a boundary $  \partial \Omega \in C^m $ , where $  m $  is finite. Consider the following elliptic PDE on $  \partial \Omega $ :
$$
\Delta_g u = f
$$
where $  \Delta_g $  is the Laplace-Beltrami operator associated with a smooth Riemannian metric $  g $ (or just the metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$), and $  f \in C^n(M) $ , with $  M $  representing the manifold : the boundary $  \partial \Omega $ .
I would like to clarify whether the regularity of the solution $  u $  can be improved to match the regularity of the boundary. Specifically, under the assumptions that $  f \in C^n(M) $  and $  m $  is the boundary regularity:

Does it follow that $  u \in C^{n+2}(M) $  on $  \Omega $  provided that $  n+2 \leq m $ ?

In other words, is elliptic regularity preserved up to the boundary in this case, or are there additional considerations that affect the regularity of $  u $  when the boundary is not $  C^\infty $  but $  C^m $  with finite $  m $ ? Furthermore, I would like to know if there are any references that clarify how the smoothness of the boundary $\partial\Omega$ affects or guarantees the $C^{n+2}$ smoothness of $u$.
I also read some similar questions such as here and here for $C^{\infty}$ smooth $\partial \Omega$, but they did not address my specific question. Any insights or references regarding this scenario for elliptic regularity on manifolds with finite regularity boundaries would be greatly appreciated.
